# Pandas shows inconsistency in rounding of floats to one decimal place

Tags: python, pandas, decimal

I have a data which looks like below

```
data = [[(21.2071607142856,)], [(Decimal('0.11904761904761904762'),)], [(9.54183035714285,)], [(9.54433035714284,)], [(17.1964285714286,)]]
```

As you can see, all of the values are `float` except one which is of type `Decimal`.

Now I need to limit the decimal to one place. So this is the script I use to do that using `pandas`

```
formatted_result_list = []
for sub_result in data:
         formatted_result = pd.DataFrame(sub_result).round(1).fillna("").to_records(index=False).tolist()
         formatted_result_list.append(formatted_result)
return formatted_result_list
```

This is what I get

```
[[(21.2,)], [(Decimal('0.11904761904761904762'),)], [(9.5,)], [(9.5,)], [(17.2,)]]
```

It is able to limit the `floats` to once decimal place but its unable to limit the value of type `Decimal`. So I change the third line to this

```
# use .astype(float)
formatted_result = pd.DataFrame(sub_result).astype(float).round(1).fillna("").to_records(index=False).tolist()
```

So now I get this

```
[[(21.2,)], [(0.1,)], [(9.5,)], [(9.5,)], [(17.2,)]]
```

But it doesn't work for data like this

```
data = [[('A', 204.593564568,), ('B', 217.421341061, 23.33), ('C', 237.296250326, 20.33), ('D', 217.464281998, 34.44), ('E', 206.329901299, 55.213)], [('F', 210.297625953,), ('G', 228.117692718, 34.22), ('H', 4, 0.99), ('I', 265.319671257, 90.99), ('K',)]]
```

**Here it literally outputs the same result.**

So what can I do to ensure if there is a `decimal`, convert it to `float` and round off and if there is a `float`, always round it off?

Comment: Do you use Pandas just for the rounding, or are your actual data inside a DataFrame? Because the initial list you show at the start of your question, doesn't require Pandas; you can just use the built-in `round` function for that, possibly inside a list-comprehension.

Comment: round(number,1) should work for both.

Answer (score 0):

Data for test:

```
#data = [[(21.2071607142856,)], [(Decimal('0.11904761904761904762'),)], [(9.54183035714285,)], [(9.54433035714284,)], [(17.1964285714286,)]]
data = [[('A', Decimal(204.593564568),), ('B', 217.421341061, 23.33), ('C', 237.296250326, 20.33), ('D', 217.464281998, 34.44), ('E', 206.329901299, 55.213)], [('F', 210.297625953,), ('G', 228.117692718, 34.22), ('H', 4, 0.99), ('I', 265.319671257, 90.99), ('K',)]]
#data = [21.2071607142856,Decimal(204.593564568)]
```

I try to create general solution for working with tuples and scalars and also with `Decimal`:

```
from decimal import Decimal

def round_custom(x):
    out = []
    for y in x:
        if isinstance(y, tuple):
            L = [round(float(z), 2) if isinstance(z, (Decimal, float)) else z for z in y]
            out.append(tuple(L))
        elif isinstance(y, (Decimal, float)):
            out.append(round(float(y), 2))
        else:
            return x

    return pd.Series(out, name=x.name)


df = pd.DataFrame(data).apply(round_custom).values.tolist()
print (df)
[[('A', 204.59), ('B', 217.42, 23.33), ('C', 237.3, 20.33), 
  ('D', 217.46, 34.44), ('E', 206.33, 55.21)], [('F', 210.3), 
  ('G', 228.12, 34.22), ('H', 4, 0.99), ('I', 265.32, 90.99), ('K',)]]
```